# flash as3 physics spring problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, spring, flash-cs4, physics

i want to do a as3 spring program, the effect is like this:
[link](http://blog.tabinda.net/actionscript/spring-physics-in-as3/)

after some research and look at some examples, my program is here:

```
public class testing_2 extends MovieClip
{
    //--------------declare variables
    private var xdif:Number;
    private var ydif:Number;
    private var xvel:Number = 0;
    private var yvel:Number = 0;

    private var totalNum:Number = 3;
    private var d:Number = 20;
    private var springArray:Array = [];

    public function testing_2()
    {
        //-------------init stuffs
        init_mc();
        init_event();
    }

    private function init_mc()
    {
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < totalNum; i++)
        {
            var mc:MovieClip = new box()  ;
            mc.num = i;
            springArray.push(mc);
            addChild(mc);
            //mc.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            //mc.y = stage.stageHeight/2 + i*d;
        }
    }

    private function init_event()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spring);
    }

    //-------------own functions
    function spring(e)
    {
    for (var i:Number = totalNum-1; i >= 0; i--){

        xdif = mouseX - springArray[i].x;
        ydif = mouseY - springArray[i].y;


        xvel +=  xdif * (0.4);
        yvel +=  ydif * (0.4);


        xvel *=  (0.8);
        yvel *=  (0.8);


        springArray[i].x +=  xvel ;
        springArray[i].y +=  yvel ;

        }
    }
```

this is not a successful program since the balls cannot separate with a certain distance, and when the balls are rolling, they are in the same circular path and cannot achieve the effect like the web site link. i think this is the problem of these`xdif = mouseX - springArray[i].x;
        ydif = mouseY - springArray[i].y;`but i can not actually point out what the problem is.

can anyone help? thank very much.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, every ball has the same behavior since there is no change between two iterations in the for loop. You should try something where the first ball refers to the mouse, the second ball to the first, the third to the second...

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < totalNum; i++){
    if (i == 0)
    {
        xdif = mouseX - springArray[i].x;
        ydif = mouseY - springArray[i].y;
    } else
    {
        xdif = springArray[i-1].x - springArray[i].x;
        ydif = springArray[i-1].y - springArray[i].y;
    }

    ...
```